# RuntimeError: Could not run 'aten::xxxx', Can't load Pytorch model trained with TPU

Tags: pytorch

Training for MLM was added based on the Japanese model of BERT.
At that time, we used TPU on Google Colab.
I get the following error when loading the created model.
Is there a way to load the model?

code

```
from transformers import BertJapaneseTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM
​
# Load pre-trained model
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('/content/drive/My Drive/Bert/models/sample/')
model.eval()
```

​
output

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    469             try:
--> 470                 state_dict = torch.load(resolved_archive_file, map_location="cpu")
    471             except Exception:
​
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    528                 return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
--> 529         return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    530 
​
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in _legacy_load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    701     unpickler.persistent_load = persistent_load
--> 702     result = unpickler.load()
    703 
​
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py in _rebuild_xla_tensor(data, dtype, device, requires_grad)
    151 def _rebuild_xla_tensor(data, dtype, device, requires_grad):
--> 152     tensor = torch.from_numpy(data).to(dtype=dtype, device=device)
    153     tensor.requires_grad = requires_grad
​
RuntimeError: Could not run 'aten::empty.memory_format' with arguments from the 'XLATensorId' backend. 'aten::empty.memory_format' is only available for these backends: [CUDATensorId, SparseCPUTensorId, VariableTensorId, CPUTensorId, MkldnnCPUTensorId, SparseCUDATensorId].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same error while using transformers, this is how I solved it.

After training on Colab, I had to send the model to the CPU. Basically, run:

```
model.to('cpu')
```

Then save the model, which allowed me to import the weights in another instance.

As implied by the error,

```
RuntimeError: Could not run 'aten::empty.memory_format' with arguments from the 'XLATensorId' backend. 'aten::empty.memory_format' is only available for these backends: [CUDATensorId, SparseCPUTensorId, VariableTensorId, CPUTensorId, MkldnnCPUTensorId, SparseCUDATensorId]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked correctly. I will mark your answer.

Comment: Np. Glad I helped :)